# Azure Mobile Center: build issue for iOS on Xamarin.Forms project

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile-center, visual-studio-app-center

I've started to develop a **Xamarin.Forms** app 2 months ago.

For this, I've chosen to use **GrialKit** for the UI, and **Visual Studio Mobile Center** for CI.
During the first weeks all worked fine: I could distribute my test versions thanks Mobile Center.

But I had to install the `2.4.0.269-pre2` package version of **Xamarin.Forms** to integrate **Iconize** to my app. Since this, I'm no longer able to build iOS releases on **Mobile Center**.
I got errors like:

> "/Users/ci/agent/vstsagent/_work/1/s/Xxx/Xxx.iOS/Xxx.iOS.csproj"
>   (Rebuild target) (1) -> (_CompileToNative target) ->    MTOUCH : error
>   MT4109: Failed to compile the generated registrar code. Please file a
>   bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com
>   [/Users/ci/agent/vstsagent/_work/1/s/Xxx/Xxx.iOS/Xxx.iOS.csproj]
>
> ```
> 11 Warning(s)
> 1 Error(s)
> ```
>
> Time Elapsed 00:03:25.71
>
> ##[error]Xamarin.iOS task failed with error Error: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Legacy_5_0_1/bin/msbuild
>   failed with return code: 1. For guidance on setting up the build
>   definition, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=760847.

I can build the app on my own iPhone from Visual Studio (Windows) or Visual Studio for Mac without any problem: so the problem comes probably from Azure Mobile Center.

I also tried to update the package to the latest version (`2.4.0.282`) but this didn't change anything...

***Would you have any suggestion or explanation?***